# How to run a method in a low priority thread in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using *gcc4.7* c++ and *boost* on linux.

I have a EventDispatcher class that use boost::signals2 like below. The `onUpdate()` can be called by multiple threads

```
class EventDispather
{
public:
void subscribe(Listener l)
{
    _signal.connect(l)
}

void onUpdate(Data data)
{
    _signal(data);
}

private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (Data)> _signal;
};
```

Now I want to add one more signal in the class to handle some low priority listeners. When onUpdate() executes, it first notify the high priority listeners. Then is should call the low priority one in a low priority thread and return immediately. New code is like below:

```
class EventDispather
{
public:
void subscribe(Listener l, Priority priority=high)
{
    if(priority == high)
    {
        _signal.connect(l);
    }
    else
    {
        _signalLowPriority.connect(l);
    }
}

void onUpdate(Data data)
{
    _signal(data);

    //how to trigger _signalLowPriority in a low priority thread?
}

private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (Data)> _signal;
    boost::signals2::signal<void (Data)> _signalLowPriority;
};
```

Questions:

- how to trigger `_signalLowPriority()` in a low priority thread and do not wait?
- Also, I do not want to create a new thread everytime `onUpdate()` excutes, but reuse a single thread.. how?

It would be great if my goal can be done in using the standard library and/or boost, but I can use any other libraries if it really helps.

Comment: What if `_signalLowPriority` gets invoked again, before the previous invocation completed?

Comment: Ideally, the single low priority thread should wait until the previous _signalLowPriority() call with previous Data object finished and call _signalLowPriority() with the new Data object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way to achive what you want is to post `_signalLowPriority` invocation to [`boost::asio::io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html), which is run in a separate thread. Here is some (untested) code:

```
class EventDispather : enable_shared_from_this<EventDispather> // simplifies lifespan management, wrt async. slot invocations
{
  EventDispather() : work_(new io_service::work(io_)) // prevent io_serivce::run() from exiting when running out of work
  {
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    // capturing "self" (even without using it) ensures that this instance will outlive the async. "queue" that uses `io_` and `_signalLowPriority` members
    thread th([self, this]() { io_.run(); });
    set_priory_with_some_native_api(thread.native_handle());
    th.detach();
  }

  void stop()
  {
    // after work_ is reset, io_service::run() will process the pending functors and then exit; thus, the above lambda will get destroyed - along with its captured "self" shared_ptr
    work_.reset();
  }

  void onUpdate(Data data)
  {
    _signal(data);
    // if io_ is running in 1 thread, all _signalLowPriority invocations will be serialized 
    io_.post([data, this]() { _signalLowPriority(data); });
  }

private:
  io_service io_;
  shared_ptr<io_serive::work> work_;
  // add here all your signals etc...
};
```

Note: while `_signalLowPriority` is threadsafe, its slots must be prepared to be invoked in a separate thread!

Certainly, you can use `thread`, `enable_shared_from_this`, `shared_ptr` either from `std` or from `boost`.

Comment: excellent work this, very insightful. Do you ever think it's wasteful to rig up an entire io_service for something simple like this?

Comment: @sehe Depends on what you mean by saying "wasteful" :). From the user p.o.v, it's just matter of 1 `#include` and a couple of lines of code.

Comment: @IgorR. What about the life of io_ member? The thread call io_.run() and detached. What happens to io_ and the thread run io_run() when EventDispather got destructed?

Comment: @Ryan Please read the comments within the code. The whole point of inheriting `enable_shared_from_this` and capturing a `shared_ptr` to `this` is to ensure that `EventDispather` doesn't get destroyed as long as `io_.run()` in progress. (Of course, this implies that `EventDispather` should be created using `new` and managed solely by means of `shared_ptr`s.)